# Why can't I use a while loop in the export default class?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

For some reason, I can't get this while-loop to work. The code in the export default class runs once, and I can never call back to it when variables are change from another LWC, and imported back to this file.

**My code:**

***mapping.js***

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { MapMarkers } from './MapMarkers';
import { SearchString, SearchState, ClickCount } from 'c/mappingBox';

// Global Variables.
let SearchStreet = '1 abc street';
let SearchCity = 'Boston';

export default class Mapping extends LightningElement {

// Method should rerun updating when the button is clicked from the MappingBox.js file; (not working).
    SearchClick(event) {

        // The address entered into the search bar.
        const ArrStreet = SearchString.split(',');
        SearchStreet = ArrStreet[0];

        // The town or city entered into the search bar.
        const ArrCity = SearchString.split(',');
        SearchCity = ArrCity[1];

        // Updates and locates the location searched.
        this.mapMarkers = MapMarkers(SearchCity, SearchState, SearchStreet);

    }
        
    // What populates, before searching is done.
    mapMarkers = MapMarkers(SearchCity, SearchState, SearchStreet);

    // Not working?
    while( ClickCount = true ){

        this.SearchClick();
        ClickCount = false;

    }

}
```

***mappingBox***

```
 // Function when the search button is clicked.
    SearchClick(event) {

        SearchString = this.SearchText;
    
        ClickCount = true;

    }
```

**More Detail:**

"ClickCount" is then export to "mapping.js" file.

For some reason I can't get the method "SearchClick" from the "mapping.js" file to rerun, so the variable can update and output a different location on the mapping function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to look at [Communicate Across the DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_pubsub) for details, but it appears that what you're looking for is a publisher-subscriber model. The documentation contains two examples, first using a generic pubsub library you can copy-paste into your project, the other using [`lightning-message-service`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation). The general idea is the same for each; you `subscribe` to a message channel when the component loads, `unsubscribe` when a component unloads, and then you can `publish` when you want to fire off an event that subscribers will receive. You can still use your shared state variable, you'll just read the values when you get a message.

```
export default class MappingBox extends LightningComponent {
  connectedCallback() {
    subscribe('searchUpdated', this.#subscription);
  }
  disconnectedCallback() {
    unsubscribe('searchUpdated', this.#subscription);
  }
  // Note use of arrow function to bind to the class scope
  #subscription = (message) => {
    // Do something 
  }
```

Comment: I been researching the "publisher-subscriber model", and just to double-check. I can run the method in **mappingBox**, when the method is clicked in **mapping**?

Comment: @Pinto Correct. You will register a method to accept the published message with the subscribe function, and that method will be called when the publish function is called.

Comment: **Update:** I was able to get it working! I looked into Lightning Message Service, and I had to create a "messageChannels" folder. Then used the subscribe and publish model, so I could rerun my method in a different LWC. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is not the right way to implement reactivity or component-to-component communication in a Lightning Web Component. You cannot use a synchronous `while` loop to poll for changes in a global variable (this would block the thread, although the way your loop is currently written it's only going to execute once anyway). You could use `setTimeout()` to create a poller, but that's not really the right approach either - you generally should not be sharing state through global variables like this.

Instead, you should rely on the LWC framework's built-in capabilities. Check out [Reactivity](https://lwc.dev/guide/javascript_reactive) and [Composition](https://lwc.dev/guide/composition#set-a-property-on-a-child-component) for detailed documentation.

In outline, here's what I think you'd want to do here - although do note that there's more than one way to accomplish something like this outcome, and you haven't shared a lot of context here. I'm assuming that `mappingBox` contains input fields. You would declare data properties in `mappingBox` to store your user input, and populate those properties via event handlers. Then, you would declare the properties that you wish to pass from your `mappingBox` component to your `Mapping` component as API properties of `Mapping`, using the `@api` decorator, and bind them to the `mappingBox` properties. (See the link above for details).

It's not entirely clear to me where the event handler "should" go for executing a search. Possibly you'd want that to be in the `mappingBox` component and have it call a [method on the child component](https://lwc.dev/guide/composition#call-a-method-on-a-child-component).

---

Separately, you should also review Caspar's answer to understand why this code does not do what you think it'll do.

Comment: They're apparently in unrelated areas of the DOM. I do generally agree that direct communication is best, but they could, for example, be in App Builder or something and unable to nest components directly. They've actually had a lot of Q's in the past while trying to figure this out.

Comment: Ah, thanks, @sfdcfox. I missed that important context. Pinto - this is really important to share so that folks can help you get to the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You are making an assignation not a comparison in the while loop. This means it will always be true.

Change it to:

```
while( ClickCount === true ){
    this.SearchClick();
    ClickCount = false;
}
```

Note the `===`